# A module is installed by it says it's not

Tags: python, python-2.7

In a virt environment I run a script:

```
(venv)my_script$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import my_script2
  File "/home/me/..../main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

But it's installed:

```
(venv)my_script$ sudo pip install numpy
....
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

What's the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `sudo pip install numpy` never installed numpy in your virtualenv. Don't use `sudo` use

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

After you have activated your virtual environment.